# Is there any symbol for an arbitrary infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, infinity

As for instance, the following are usual symbols for particular infinite sets:

> $\mathbb N$ : the natural numbers
>
> $\mathbb Z$ : the integers,
>
> $\mathbb Q$ : the rationals,
>
> $\mathbb R$ : the real numbers,
>
> $\mathbb C$ : the set of complex numbers.

Let us call $S$, an infinite set in general. Is there any known symbol to replace $S$? Probably, $\infty$ is not a good choice. Will it be appropriate to write $S_{\infty}$ to mean that $S$ is an infinite set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "usual" symbol.  Just say "let $S$ be an infinite set".

Comment: Also, note that "$S_\infty$" denotes the group of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$.